# Why does \listfiles not show version info for custom packages (styles/.sty files)?

Tags: packages

Skip ahead to the Log Output section to see my problem.

Let's assume the following file structure:

```
Root
  - Preamble.tex
 |- Libraries
   |- Addresses
      - addresses.sty
 |- Documents
   |- UserManual
      - UserManual.tex
```

## Inside of Preamble.tex

```
% ----------------------
% Load Addresses Library
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Libraries/Addresses/addresses}
```

## Inside of Addresses

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{addresses}[2016/03/01 Provides Addresses for Highly Specialized Services Documentation]

\def\localaddress{
Highly~Specialized~Services~GmbH\\
Eisenloven~00\\
38744~Timbuktu\\
Mali\\
Phone:~+00~101~101011
}
```

## Inside of UserManual.tex

```
\listfiles
\input{../../Preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\localaddress\
\end{document}
```

## Log Output Snippet

Where is the version info on the addresses.sty line?

```
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
../../Libraries/Addresses/addresses.sty
```

Comment: Not directly importnat here, but you shouldn't have a path in the argument of `\usepackage`: put `addresses.sty` where TeX can find it (local tree) and load just with `\usepackge{addresses}`.

Comment: @JosephWright It is not an option, unfortunately, because the entire documentation is self-contained in a version control system (we happen to be using subversion). A checkout should rely only on a complete and unmodified (for good maintenance practice) TeX Live Installation. This way, any user (on any host with TeX Live) can check out the source files and have a fully operational documentation system.

Comment: You can set `TEXINPUTS` or `TEXMFHOME` from a script or other build set up: there's not requirement that all 'local' files have to go into a single tree. (Though really if files are specific to a single project they should simply all be in the same directory.)

Comment: You must have a warning from latex that `\usepackage{Libraries/Addresses/addresses}` does not match `addresses` don't ignore warnings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism in `\usepackage`, *etc.*, assume that files are located 'where  TeX can find them', *i.e.* either 'here', in a location specified by `TEXINPUTS` or in a TeX tree such as the main installation tree, one of those listed in `TEXMFHOME`, *etc.* Specifically, what happens here is:

- LaTeX looks for a file `Libraries/Addresses/addresses.sty`, finds it and loads it
- `\ProvidesFile` records version information in `\ver@Libraries/Addresses/addresses.sty`
- `\listfiles` requests a file list, which contains the 'names' of all of the files loaded
- The process for building a file list *only* looks for versions based on the file name itself, so looks for `\ver@addresses.sty` and produces no output as it doesn't exist

Notably, the same issue would happen if you try to load the same file twice: as far as the LaTeX mechanisms are concerned, `addresses.sty`, `foo/addresses.sty` and `foo/bar/addresses.sty` are distinct file names.

---

As the above shows, the systems build in to LaTeX *strongly* expect that files *names* are given not file *paths*. This can be handled by

- Placing files 'here'
- Placing them in a local TeX tree set up for access using `TEXMFHOME` (using an environmental variable or the MiKTeX manager where that is appropriate)
- Adjusting `TEXINPUTS` to point to additional locations

Note that the latter mechanisms both allow multiple paths to be added, so this can be adjusted on a per-project basis.

Comment: Is there any way to trick LaTeX into setting `\ver@addresses.sty` despite being called `\ver@foo/addresses.sty`? I know TEXINPUTS is a good solution, but I can't be maintaining environment variables on every machine (especially since every developer has his or her own preferred folder naming scheme for SVN checkouts, which would break any TEXINPUTS). That is not a portable solution for a large operation (not yet anyway).

Comment: @macmadness86 using a path in `\usepackage` is basically an _error_ obviously any part of latex can be redefined, but you shouldn't redefine that. If you really want to do that better to use `\Providespackage{Libraries/Addresses/addresses}` so that the declared name matches the name that you use in `\usepackage`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Understood. I will have to do it this way until I find a  portable solution for the paths as Joseph suggested. I'd prefer to do things the "clean" and "right" way.